# Как получить current_user_id из wordpress в node js?

Tags: wordpress, node.js, websocket

Есть сайт на wordpress, в папке plugins у меня находится проект на Node js. 
В index.html (клиентская часть, в основном там js), есть контент, который я должен показать только зарегистрированным пользователям. Мне нужно выяснить данные зарегистрированного в wordpress пользователя и передать их в node js.

С помощью Ajax передаю user id из php в файл js. Вот часть моего кода:
WP / function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_cur_user_id', 'get_cur_user_id'); 
function get_cur_user_id(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'wt_nonce', 'wt_nonce_code' );

    $wt_name = esc_attr($_POST['wt_name']);
    $wt_user_id = esc_attr($_POST['wt_user_id']);

    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wt_ajax_data' );
function wt_ajax_data() {

    wp_enqueue_script('ajax_get_cur_user_id', plugins_url('/js/ajax_get_cur_user_id.js'), array( 'jquery' ));

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_get_cur_user_id', 'wt_data_user', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'wt_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wt_nonce'),
        'wt_name' => wp_get_current_user()->display_name,
        'wt_user_id' => wp_get_current_user()->id
    ));
}
```

В файле JS я получаю данные и отправляю их в node js, который, как я понимаю, вообще не знает о существовании WordPress. Код:
JS / ajax_get_cur_user_id.js

```
(function($) {
    $.getScript( "/socket.io/socket.io.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {

        var socket = io('/', {path : '/trade/socket.io'});
        var data = {
            action: 'cur_user_id',
            wt_nonce_code: wt_data_user.wt_nonce,
            wt_name: wt_data_user.wt_name,
            wt_user_id: wt_data_user.wt_user_id
        };

        $.post( wt_data_user.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            socket.emit('validate', wt_data_user);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Таким образом я получаю ID зарегистрированного пользователя на странице "index.html" - (node js). Этого я и добивался, но, когда все сделал, увидел следующую проблему. 
index.html - это страница, ссылка на которую есть в личном кабинете каждого зарегистрированного пользователя. На данный момент index.html является как бы общей комнатой группового чата. Т.е, если в личный кабинет вошел пользователь, в index.html отображается user ID, того, кто последний загрузил/обновил страницу wordpress и этот ID показывается всем, кто находится на странице index.html. Для моих целей этого быть не должно. Мне нужно добиться того, чтобы на странице index.html отображались данные только активного пользователя, т.е, user_id = 1 видит только ID - 1, для user_id = 2 показывается ID - 2 вне зависимости от того, кто последний залогинился или обновил страницу.

Моя окончательная цель: определить пользователя и изменить его данные в базе данных. Не знаю, как сделать такую проверку... Помогите, пожалуйста, буду рад любому совету.

Answer (score 0):

Так у вас ничего не выйдет. О том, что пользователь залогинен, никаких отметок в базе не ставится. Есть куки, которые держит браузер, они проверяются на сервере при обращении. Понятие "текущий пользователь" существует только при обращении к WordPress. Ядро сверяет куки с информацией в базе данных и делает вывод, что пользователь с id=5 сейчас активен.

В общем, вам надо из node делать ajax-запрос в WP, чтобы узнать, какой пользователь является текущим в данном окне браузера.

И вообще, не надо лазить в базу "руками". В WordPress есть функции на все случаи жизни.

Comment: А вы не подскажете, если это не слишком большой код, как может выглядеть такой запрос?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html базовые сведения об ajax в WordPress. В php коде вам надо использовать `wp_get_current_user()`

Comment: Спасибо, поразбираюсь. Хотел еще спросить: https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi это мне не поможет? Пока не помогло, но стоит ли дальше разбираться в этом?

Comment: Это должно помочь, судя по описанию. REST API - очень мощная подсиситема в WP, предоставляет доступ ко всем ресурсам.

Comment: ajax как раз для того, чтобы инициировать запрос к WP, там его обработать и вернуть ответ в js.

Comment: Могли бы вы еще раз прочитать мой вопрос? Я отредактировал его. Все это я смог сделать благодаря вашим подсказкам, надеюсь вы снова сможете мне помочь.

Comment: Ваша функция `get_cur_user_id()` не работает совсем. Она ничего не делает. Для коммуникации должен быть вывод `echo` перед `die()`. Скрипт `ajax_get_cur_user_id.js`, тем, не менее, получает данные от сервера через `wp_localize_script()` (можете увидеть эти данные как CDATA в браузере - View Page Source).

Comment: Теперь по сути: кто генерирует страницу index.html? Я так понимаю, что node. Так вот, при генерации страницы, надо использовать user_id, полученный от js. В базе (насколько я понимаю вашу задачу) вам делать нечего. Там нет отметки, кто когда входил, кто когда обновил страницу - ничего, ноль. Всё в куках. Вы в `ajax_get_cur_user_id.js` получили id пользователя, делаете `post` в ноду, ну и передайте ей id пользователя, чтобы она сгенерила index.html под него.